# Combine MVVM and n-layered Architecture with Firestore in Backend

Tags: android, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to re-structure my codebase to implement `MVVM` architecture and 3-layered architecture using Android Architecture Components.

The `MainActivity.java` file contains a `Fragment`, and this `Fragment` is where most of the user interactions take place. The user provides an input, and based on that input I want to be able to hit the `Firebase Firestore` database to fetch the relevant data and then display it on the UI. This approach should follow the `Separation of Concerns` principle.

Currently, upon receiving user input on the `Fragment`, I relay the input to its parent activity, i.e., `MainActivity.java` using an `Interface`, and then call a function **`FetchUserRequestedData`**. Once I receive the data, I display it appropriately on the UI (not a part of the Fragment).

However, I want my 1) business logic layer, 2) database access layer, and 3) UI layer in separate packages. (To ensure that I follow the n-layered architecture pattern)

Also, with `Firestore` as the database for my app, I'm not sure how the flow of both, input from user and output data from `Firestore` should be handled all the way from the data layer to the UI model. Note that `Firestore` database calls are asynchronous.

How can I set up my codebase to follow the correct communication model between the three layers so that it follows both `MVVM` and n-layered architecture?

Code is like this:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentClass.DataPasser {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private ArrayList<DataType> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .
        .
        .
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        .
        .
        .
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserInput(DataType input) {
        dataList = dataProvider.ProvideData(input);
        //update UI using this dataList
    }
}
```

FragmentClass.java

```
public class FragmentClass extends CustomFragmentClass {

    DataPasser dataPasser;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        dataPasser = (DataPasser) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle inState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, inState);

        // Do app specific setup logic.


        return Content.getContentView();
    }

    @Override
    public void userProvidedInput(DataType userInput) { //part of CustomFragmentClass
        super.userProvidedInput(userInput);

        dataPasser.onUserInput(userInput); //defined in MainActivity.java
    }


    public interface DataPasser { //interface class to send user input to main activity

        public void onUserInput(DataType input);
    }

}
```

DataProvider.java

```
public class DataProvider {

    private ArrayList<DataType> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataFetcher dataFetcher = new DataFetcher();

    public ArrayList<DataType> ProvideData(String userInput) {

        dataList = dataFetcher(userInput);
        return dataList;
    }

    private ArrayList<DataType> dataFetcher(String userInput) {
        ArrayList<DataType> fetchedData = new ArrayList<>();

        fetchedData = dataFetcher.DatabaseCaller(userInput);

        return fetchedData;
    }
}
```

DataFetcher.java

```
public class DataFetcher {

    ArrayList<DataType> dataList;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    public ArrayList<DataType> DatabaseCaller(String userInput) {

    //formulate query based on userInput
    //hit database and fetch dataList
    
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Created three classes: MainActivity, DataProvider, and DataFetcher. Then created object of DataFetcher in DataProvider, and DataProvider in MainActivity. Passed user argument to a function of DataProvider, which in turn passes it to a function of DataFetcher. DataFetcher's function formulates the firestore query.

Comment: Also tried this approach, [link](https://evanamargain.com/android/android-livedata-and-viewmodel-in-java-tutorial/), didn't work as expected.

Comment: Instead of describing the code, please add it to your question.

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo , I've added the code to my question, please take a look.

Comment: Hi, here are 2 examples of implementing the Android MVVM Architectural Pattern [eg. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267099/how-to-use-android-mvvm-pattern-with-fragments), [eg. 2](https://www.journaldev.com/20292/android-mvvm-design-pattern). Also In this repo you can find a detailed sample app that implements MVVM architecture using Dagger2, Room, RxJava, FastAndroidNetworking, PlaceHolderView and AndroidDebugDatabase. And In this article you will find an implementation example based on MVVM pattern and repository pattern.